# Get previous transforms Maya

Tags: python, maya, mel

Is there a way using NODES to get the previous transforms or in my case translations, from time? I have written a simple expression that does just this but I really want to achieve this with nodes.

$transx = `getattr 'objname.tx' -frame time -1;`

Or something similar to that anyway I can't completely remember but it was using getatrr in an expression.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Expressions nodes are nodes, tough *getAttr* inside a expression node breaks the nodal flow. But yes,  you can store the value from previous run with a  **frameCache** node. Or you can just store the value inside a attribute in the expression.

```
node.tx = node.cacheTx;
node.cacheTx = objname.tx;
```

This is much faster as it doesn't break the attribute evaluation flow. Both of these mechanisms have a flaw tough they wont evaluate out of time context if it has changed between the frame change. Which is what Maya users do all the time, leading to poor user feedback. Actually there's little you can do with this sort of implementing a very convoluted custom node.

The reason this is hard is because Maya users have succeed with their practical actions to break Mayas time mechanism. The developers have then capitulated under user pressure and allowed this, but it has broken Mayas time evaluation cycle so that not everything can be queried with a time context shift. Making it hard to make Difference equation solvers in Maya. Certainly, in this particular case the node is not especially hard to make but a node that actually works in most instances is hard.

Comment: I don't really understand how the code you provided wouldget the "previous" translationX, would they not just equal the same values?

Comment: @JulianMann Yes and i did